# Why does my WebSockets handshake fail with ERR_CONNECTION_RESET?

Tags: node.js, websocket, sails.js, sails.io.js

I've just created a new [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) app with

```
sails new testProject
```

Then I did

```
sails lift
```

Now I navigate to my address (`http://153.92.xx.xxx:1337`) and everything works.

[image: sails app]

However, I know that sails uses XHR by default but tries to upgrade to WebSockets if it can. No matter what I try I can't get WebSockets to work.

I can see that the app tries to connect but is just (pending) for about 18 seconds before it gives up. It then goes back to XHR.

[image: websockets error]

The error reads:

> `WebSocket connection to 'ws://153.92.xx.xxx:1337/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.11.0&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=8qjNepcGV5Rh3VvzAAAA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

**What could I be doing wrong?**

- Sailsjs v0.11.2
- Nodejs v0.12.7
- Debian 8 x64
- iptables has full ACCEPT on everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is because of a **personal firewall**.

- Changing the port from 1337 to 80 made everything work.
- Accessing the site from a different machine worked ok.

My best guess is that a personal firewall that was on my machine blocks websockets if they are not using "standard" ports.

Comment: If this answers your question for you, then please mark your answer as accepted to remove it from the open questions.

Comment: @gzost I have to wait 24 hours before I can do that ;)

Comment: I didn't know that - so thanks for setting me right on this!